# Is it possible to change data format in "TTF" file?

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

For example, if we type "A" on the keyboard, it will also be displayed as "A" on the screen.

And some of fonts are designed to do this another shape which like more large or bold.

I think, This is the only thing what we can do by changing font.

But some special fonts are designed to do this different shape.

For example, when I type "A" but it will be displayed "B" on display. Also "C" to "D", "F" to "A", etc..

I want to know how to make this TTF file.

And is it possible to restore original font? or Can is find its transform rule?

I don't know it is not allowed in stackoverflow, but if you want i give you example fonts.

Comment: you can use font edit/make tools and just "draw" B for the character A

Comment: Can? Yes. Is it legal? That depends on the font license (commercial fonts absolutely won't allow this, and free fonts generally don't let you modify the core behaviour of the font without renaming it - and I don't mean filename, but encoded font name). As for "how", you'd either change the CMAP information or add GSUB rules, using a font editor or something like fonttool's `ttx`. So to continue: Can? Yes. Is it easy? No, not if you've never done this before.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans
Can i ask one more thing?
What is fonttool's ttx and where can i download it?

Comment: https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/